# How do I retrieve all files in linux for given directory level. I want to absolute path aswell as the filename

Tags: linux, grep, pipe, depth

I'm trying to retrieve all files for a given directory level. The files retrieved should also show absolute path.

```
git ls-files | cut -f1 | uniq | grep '.xml'
```

I expect the results to be a list of files in the directory level/depth 1.

Comment: Thank you, that did the job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `find`: using `-maxdepth` flag set to 1, `-type f` to list only files, `-iname` to list file of matching type. `-exec` to perform some action on the matched files. `readlink -f` to print the full path of the files.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.xml" -exec readlink -f {} \;
```